# How to put space between groups of stacked bars in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to group the stacks spatially in pairs such that the 0W treatment is close to the corresponding 6W treatment with bigger spaces between pairs of different treatments.  I've included a column "group" to show which pairs should go together.

Data:

```
       trt            org   time  copy     group
1    Notill_D0 0W    fungi   0W 9.78e+07     a
2  Notill_D707 0W    fungi   0W 1.55e+07     b
3    Native_D0 0W    fungi   0W 4.02e+07     c
4  Native_D707 0W    fungi   0W 1.04e+07     d
5    Notill_D0 6W    fungi   6W 5.51e+07     a
6  Notill_D707 6W    fungi   6W 1.43e+07     d
7    Native_D0 6W    fungi   6W 1.60e+07     c
8  Native_D707 6W    fungi   6W 8.64e+06     b
9    Notill_D0 0W bacteria   0W 2.98e+08     a
10 Notill_D707 0W bacteria   0W 7.79e+07     b
11   Native_D0 0W bacteria   0W 2.33e+08     c
12 Native_D707 0W bacteria   0W 2.20e+08     d
13   Notill_D0 6W bacteria   6W 3.37e+08     a
14 Notill_D707 6W bacteria   6W 8.84e+07     d
15   Native_D0 6W bacteria   6W 3.24e+08     c
16 Native_D707 6W bacteria   6W 1.89e+08     b
```

dput:

```
structure(list(trt = structure(c(5L, 7L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 8L, 2L, 
4L, 5L, 7L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 8L, 2L, 4L), .Label = c("Native_D0 0W", 
"Native_D0 6W", "Native_D707 0W", "Native_D707 6W", "Notill_D0 0W", 
"Notill_D0 6W", "Notill_D707 0W", "Notill_D707 6W"), class = "factor"), 
    org = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("bacteria", "fungi"), class = "factor"), 
    time = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("0W", "6W"), class = "factor"), 
    copy = c(97800000, 15500000, 40200000, 10400000, 55100000, 
    14300000, 1.6e+07, 8640000, 2.98e+08, 77900000, 2.33e+08, 
    2.2e+08, 3.37e+08, 88400000, 3.24e+08, 1.89e+08), group = structure(c(1L, 
    2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L
    ), .Label = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("trt", 
"org", "time", "copy", "group"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-16L))
```

code:

```
    colvec <-c("blue", "orange")

ggplot(Suz2, aes(factor(trt), copy)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(fill = factor(org)), stat="identity", width = 0.7) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = colvec)+
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill='white', colour='white'), 
        panel.grid = element_line(color = NA),
        panel.grid.minor = element_line(color = NA),
        panel.border = element_rect(fill = NA, color = "black"),
        axis.text.x  = element_text(size=10, colour="black", face = "bold"),  
        axis.title.x = element_text(vjust=0.1, face = "bold"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size=12, colour="black"),
        axis.title.y = element_text(vjust=0.2, size = 12, face = "bold"))
```

Comment: You will find people more willing to help if you put the data in a more easily usable form. Try using `dput()` on your dataframe, which will give us the data in a way that can be easily used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can do what you want with `facet`, if the plot you made is `p`, just add:

```
p + facet_wrap(~group,nrow = 1)
```

to get:
[image]

If you're after something different, please redefine.